# AVAudioPlayer causing app to crash

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, avplayer, avaudioplayer

I am working on an app that receives an integer every 200MS and will play a tone for the size of the integer evenly spread over the next 200MS interval. The sound works fine but the app crashes at completely random times. I originally was testing on an ipod(5th gen) and it crashes anywhere between 1 min and 10 min giving me the error

> "EXC_BREAKPOINT (EXC_ARM_BREAKPOINT, subcode=0xdefe)"

Before I was getting an `EXC_BAD_ACCESS` but after moving the player definition to the `AppDelegate` among other attempted fixes the message is now the ARM Breakpoint one. I also tried on my iPhone 6S+ and it ran for over 15 min with no crashes.

The player is defined within the ViewController(as suggested by another post on here) like so:

```
var audioPlayer: AVAudioPlayer!
```

Here is the code within a view controller class that works to play the tone:

```
//called for every beep
@objc func playSound() {
    toneCount += 1
    if toneCount >= totalTones{
        if toneTimer != nil {
            toneTimer?.invalidate()
            toneTimer = nil
        }
    }
    do{
        guard let url = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "geiger", withExtension: "mp3") else { return }
        audioPlayer = try AVAudioPlayer(contentsOf: url, fileTypeHint: AVFileType.mp3.rawValue)
        try AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setCategory(AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback)
        try AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setActive(true)
        audioPlayer.play()
    }catch{
        print("failed")
    }

}
```

This is output to console when the crash happens:

```
"[AVAudioPlayer performSelector:withObject:]: message sent to deallocated instance 0x1886b590"
```

In the stackframe(not sure if this is correct term, but the frame to the left of the console output) the player variable is brought up showing it is equal to (`AVAudioPlayer`)? and within the player variable is `"ObjectiveC.NSObject"` which itself is empty

Really not too sure what else to try as I've tried making player a weak variable, but then the tone doesn't play. I've tried defining it in the view controller. It also puzzles me as to why it seems to not crash on the iphone 6S+ and why it is completely random as to when the crash happens.

I've also tried to do a singleton class in a separate file like this:

```
let tone = soundtest()

class soundtest {
    func playTone() {
        do{
            print("played Sound")
            guard let url = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "geiger", withExtension: "mp3") else { return }
            let audioPlayer = try AVAudioPlayer(contentsOf: url, fileTypeHint: AVFileType.mp3.rawValue)
            try AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setCategory(AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback)
            try AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setActive(true)
            audioPlayer.play()
        }catch{
            print("failed")
        }
    }
}
```

the attempt to play the tone sound like this:

```
tone.playTone()
```

and now the sound doesnt play

Comment: Can you clarify, you said that `player` is defined in `AppDelegate`, and `playSound` in viewController. How did you directly get the `player` variable in `playSound`?

Comment: i was using player as a global variable, another post suggested that. But anyways I think I've solved the issue, I defined the player as "var audioPlayer: AVAudioPlayer?" within the ViewController class then inside the playSound function I now declare player as "self.audioPlayer = try AVAudioPlayer(contentsOf: url, fileTypeHint: AVFileType.mp3.rawValue)". I will add as a solution if it goes 15 min without crashing. If it fails, do you have any other ideas

Comment: guard let url = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "geiger", withExtension: "mp3") else { return }
            self.audioPlayer = try AVAudioPlayer(contentsOf: url, fileTypeHint: AVFileType.mp3.rawValue)
            try AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setCategory(AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback)
            try AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setActive(true)
            if self.audioPlayer != nil{
                self.audioPlayer?.play()
            }else{
                print("player was nil")
            }

Comment: I now have this within a do statement within the playSound function and i removed the definition from the appDelegate. still crashed after 5 min

Comment: The ipod may have been on old build when it threw the error again. its been running for over 10 min right now so the above changes may have fixed.

Comment: it crashed after 20 Minutes... I have no clue what to do

Comment: Does it crash with the same message `sent to deallocated instance`? For test purpose you can remove storing `player` at all. And on each `playSound` do clean init of it.

Comment: I've missed some points in your code, when read previously. You stored `AVAudioPlayer` in `player`. But when you call `playSound` again it will reinit. Then I don't understand, what is the purpose of `player != nil` condition?

Comment: Also, can you add your edited version of code?

Comment: @TienNguyen I was away for the weekend so I did not see your comment. I have updated the code in the main post and the reason i had player != nil was because in my mind what is going on is that player is equal to nil and then something tries to access it and that is what causes the crash. Or am I wrong in saying that?

Comment: I may be misunderstanding, but why have you defined two `AVAudioPlayer`? Just the one in the view controller is needed right?

Comment: @PranavKasetti yes I removed it from the AppDelegate, it is now defined in the ViewController

Comment: @Mumphus does it crash if you call 2 `playSound()` one after another immediately?

Comment: yes that was it, thank you. It was a very short audio clip but I guess the crash happened when a tone was played before the other was finished. I now check if the player is playing and if so, stop it.

Comment: @Mumphus I think the crash can be because you release `audioPlayer` before the sound end. Because on each `playSound` you override `audioPlayer` variable. Probably you could store them in array, add delegate to listen sound end, then release it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most likely the crash is happening because the `audioPlayer` was released before the sound end. To prevent that, as your wrote in comment, you can check if player is playing sound before calling `playSound`. Or store each `player` in array, then release when sound end.

Comment: Thank you! I will keep this in mind, right now I stop the sound before playing the next, but I think that would mean if sounds play very fast then they might get cut off before finishing or maybe not even play at all. As of right now I will leave it as it because it doesn't crash anymore but once I can focus on this more I will investigate it using your advice!

Comment: @Mumphus, sure, then you can close the question. Have a nice day! :)